# c++ Creating a class in seperate .cpp and .h files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to declare the class "graphics" but in graphics.cpp, I get the error.

> 'graphics' is not a class or namespace name.

it says the location of the error is

> graphics::graphics()

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and in my code, graphics is highlighted as a class.. yet it is apparently not considered a class by graphics.cpp? Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Here is my code

```
//graphics.h
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

struct SDL_Window;
struct SDL_Renderer;

class graphics
{
public:
     graphics();
     ~graphics();
private:
     SDL_Window* _window;
     SDL_Renderer* _renderer;
};

#endif
```

and then

```
//graphics.cpp
#include "graphics.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

graphics::graphics() {}
graphics::~graphics() {}
```

Comment: Hmm, `graphics::graphics()` should work well, unless you're not missing something elsewhere you don't show.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, but then I'mnot using VS or SDL. Try removing as much of the code from your example as you can, while still reproducing the error, ad if the problem still isn't obvious, post a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you put `#ifdef GRAPHICS_H` `#error test` `#endif` just before `#include "graphics.h"`, do you get an error saying "test"?

Comment: In Visual Studio if you use Precompiled headers `#include "stdafx.h"` has to be the before other c++ statements or includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Pre-compiled headers

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "graphics.h"
#include "stdafx.h" <<<<< must always be included before anything else
```

Change to

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SDL.h"
#include "graphics.h"
```

The compiler should output this error along with your given error.